# Unity 5.6 VR VRSettings.supportedDevices is empty

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, asus

I'm migrating my game to Unity 5.6 and trying to use the native VR support for Cardboard. However the pp doesn't go to VR mode at all I guess that's because when I call `VRSettings.supportedDevices` returns an empty `string[]`. The device is ASUS Zenfone 2 which supports VR mode and I have been using it with older versions of Unity in VR mode.

Anyone had this problem before?

Here is the code:

```
IEnumerator LoadDevice(string newDevice)
{
    VRSettings.LoadDeviceByName(newDevice);
    yield return null;
    VRSettings.enabled = true;
    Debug.Log ("********************** SUPPORTED DEVICES 2: " + VRSettings.supportedDevices.Length);
    Debug.Log ("********************** DEVICE: " + VRSettings.loadedDeviceName);
    Debug.Log ("********************** ENABLED: " + VRSettings.enabled);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`VRSettings.supportedDevices`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/VR.VRSettings-supportedDevices.html) returns a list of supported VR devices that were included at build time.

`VRSettings.supportedDevices` is empty because you did not add it to the Editor yet. You mentioned Cardboard, so add Cardboard to the *Virtual Reality SDKs* list from the *Player Settings*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I do have Cardboard added there.

Comment: Make sure to switch to Android platform sine ASUS Zenfone 2 is an Android device. Please post code of how you are using `VRSettings.supportedDevices`. This works for me. I use 5.6.0b10 beta. Also try this in a build and see if it works.

Comment: It's switched to Android in Build Settings.

Comment: Again, post the code of how you are using `VRSettings.supportedDevices` and what makes you think it is null. Also, if this problem is happening in the Editor, build it and run it on the device then tell me what happens..

Comment: I've edited the original question with my code.
I am running it on the device, I think I mentioned that.
I'm getting this when I run `adb logcat` in terminal
"`********************** VR DEVICE: `"

Comment: Hi, why not use a `Text` component to do the debugging on Android. That would be much more easier for you. Can you comment out the `LoadDevice` function then put `UnityEngine.Debug.Log(VRSettings.supportedDevices.Length);` and  
`UnityEngine.Debug.Log(VRSettings.supportedDevices[0]);` in the Awake function. Run this in the Editor then run it on your device. Tell me the result you got from both the Editor and your Android device.

Comment: OK so I printed out the output from `VRSettings.supportedDevices` and the `cardboard` entry is there but still no luck launching VR mode. I have found this error in the log and I think it might be why it doesn't work: `DllNotFoundException: gvr`